# Swift: Rounded Corners on Camera View

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to implement rounded corners on my RecordingViewController(which has the camera view).I tried going into the app delegate and changing the corner radius of the window however, it seemed to not work. I believe the issue is with this method (AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill), it seems to fill the entire screen and takes no consideration to changing the window corner radius. Any ideas?

Comment: what do yo mean by camrera view ? Do you mean `image picker controller` ?

Comment: set as self.viewPic?.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?   
  var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
```

First of all create a UIView and give it corner radius.
After that add AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer as sublayer to that view.

```
    myView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = myView.layer.bounds
    myView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was the masksToBounds step that was causing my problem. When I added that I was able to get the border to work correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidVincentGagne Border radius not coming up in final output video